# Pausing for input in vagrant shell script

Tags: git, shell, vagrant

I am using the VVV vagrant box (https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV)

I am trying to build my own shell script that downloads a repository.

I am doing this:

```
echo "cloning staging server repo"

git clone https://User@github.com/rep/therepo.git
```

If I run this shell script on its own then the command prompt will ask me to enter a password.  This is the way I wish it to work.

When I run `vagrant provision` it fails instantly because no password is supplied.  I don't want to save the password as part of the URL.

Is there a way to make it work as I intend over https during provision or is the only way for me to make it work by cloning it through SSH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a method to have an interactive prompt with Vagrant. It seems you can either (a) pass the value using `args` inside your `config.vm.provision` or (b) load a file with the password.

There are great examples of syntax [here](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html), like this one:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell",
    inline: "/bin/sh /path/to/the/script/already/on/the/guest.sh"
end
```

You can either call the script from your provisioner, like shown above, or write some more ruby to do so.